# Akismet java doesn't work even with explicit SPAM

Tags: java, servlets, akismet

I'm using the java API for Akismet, to detect spam ([Akismet Java API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akismet-java)) I put all the parameters as it specifies and it doesn't work for me, I mean... always return that my comment has not spam inside, but that's not true! I've trying with a lot of explicit spam in the comments and Akismet always says that there's not spam.

Here is my code (adapted to be understood):

```
Akismet akismet = new Akismet(MY_AKISMET_KEY, MY_WEB);
boolean ok = akismet.commentCheck(
   "127.0.0.1", //submitter ipAddress
   "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1\"", //userAgent
   "http://www.test.com/blog", //referrer
   "http://test.com/blog/post=1", //permalink
   "comment", //comment type
   "dumb", //author
   "dumb@dumb.com", //email
   "http://www.dumb.com", // authorURL
   "Visit www.mypage.com, the best!", //Text to check
   null);
```

You can see the explicit SPAM in the comment: "Visit www.mypage.com, the best!". Despite this, the boolean value is always false. I've tried a lot of comments and it is always false. I think everything is well-written.

This API says almost everything is optional, but performance can drop dramatically if you exclude certain elements (not important for now).

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!